# Node.js/Express Open-source example websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What are some great open-source projects that show advanced production quality use of Node.js, preferably with the Express framework?  The two closest things I have found are:

- [Let's Make a Web App](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/)
- [Blog Rolling With Express](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)

Comment: Should make this community wiki before it gets downvoted

Comment: It looks like I can't make it a wiki until one of these requirements are met: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355297/is-using-node-js-or-ringojs-safe-for-live-websites/7355540

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following projects:

- [habitrpg](https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg) (with express)
- [npmjs.org](https://github.com/isaacs/npmjs.org)
- [BrowserQuest](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest)

Comment: habitrpg is one of the coolest little open-source projects I've seen - dunno how it is as an OS project, but very cool site/project